# Redirect to new domain that serves new and different content

Tags: url-rewriting, redirect, domain

**What I want to do:**

1. Redirect `old domain` to `new domain`
2. Redirect all urls of `old domain` to `new domain`'s home page (Old and New site serves different contents)

**What I've done:**

- 301 redirect `old domain` to `new domain` by using

`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com$1 [R=permanent,L]`

- changed site url and home address of the `old domain` to `new domain`

**Problems:**

- It only redirects the home address (`Old-Example.com`) but not the content of the old website.
- The 404 pages of `old website` are still reflecting `old domain`

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO. You're redirecting the users of old website to a new website which will **not** send the content to the new site. In order to do that what you can do is install a plugin, I usually recommend [Updraft plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/updraftplus/) to transfer the content of old site to the new site.

This is not only easy to use but also helps in transfering everything including media and database from the site a (old site) to the new site (site b).

Edit:
Update your `.htaccess` to something like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^OLDDOMAIN\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://NEWDOMAIN.com [R=301,L]
```

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Thanks. I've edited my question to provide more clarity. I'm trying to redirect all urls of old domain to new domain's homepage. I don't want to transfer content of the old site to new site.

Comment: Edited my question. Please check now.

Comment: Thanks! I've tried that method before posting here. That works with redirecting *oldexample.com* to *newexample.com*. However, it still produces the problems that I have highlighted in my original post. The *oldexample.com/wp-admin* is not redirected. The content pages of *oldexample.com* produced 404s.

Comment: followSymLinks will resolve this issue. and wp-admin will not be redirected to the new domain. What are you actually trying to do? Are you trying to serve new content on new domain or old content on new domain?

Comment: It doesn't work on my end. It only redirects olddomain.com to newdomain.com. I'd like to redirect all urls of old domain to the home page of new domain. For e.g, olddomain.com to newdomain.com. olddomain.com/123 to newdomain.com, olddomain.com/123/123 to newdomain.com. Is there a way to do it site wide dynamically

Comment: Thanks. Finally got it fixed with a plugin.